# Duplicate column exception when reading Parquet files from S3A using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet

I have a schema with multiple Int8 and String columns that I have written into Parquet format and stored in an S3A bucket for use later.

When I try to read this parquet file using `SqlContext.read.option("mergeSchema","false").parquet("s3a://....")`, I get the following exception.

I have tried using parquet-tools(with schema and meta options) to read the parquet file, but I am getting an unknown command error.

```
*Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Duplicate column(s) : "Int8", "String" found, cannot save to parquet format;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation.checkConstraints(ParquetRelation.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation.dataSchema(ParquetRelation.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.schema$lzycompute(interfaces.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.schema(interfaces.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation.<init>(LogicalRelation.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.baseRelationToDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.parquetFile(SQLContext.scala:1052)
    :
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)*
```

How do I ensure that the parquet files are being written correctly? Does anybody know how this duplicate columns error can be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to the parquet file being corrupted. Once I ensured the parquet format was correct using parquet-tools, I was able to read back from the parquet file into Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SqlContext.read.option("mergeSchema","true").parquet("s3a://....")
```

Here is the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging) for this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.Did not help unfortunately.

Comment: I cannot paste the entire code, but if it helps, I read from parquet successfully and wrote to s3a and I am trying to read from the S3A 
    val engf = sqlContext.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("s3a://<path of parquet file>")

Comment: can you be little more specific , like , created data frame using parquet file and later written back , something like this.

Comment: I have parquet data on my local FS. I read it into a dataframe and wrote it into S3 (this is the part of the code I cannot share, sorry),I am trying to read back the parquet file from the S3 bucket.  I have several columns of int8 and string types, and I believe the exception is thrown when the sqlContext.read is encountering duplicate columns with the same type.
I am also not sure why the exception says, cannot save to parquet format, when I am trying to read  parquet data.